# Difference between [] and [[]] in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am taking a course on Coursera titled "Data Analysis with Python". I am new to Python. I have some experience with C and MATLAB. That's why I haven't faced that much problem except for one thing.

At first please take a look at the following code.

```
import pandas as pd

#path of data
path = 'https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBMDeveloperSkillsNetwork-DA0101EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/Data%20files/automobileEDA.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

lm = LinearRegression()

X = df[['highway-mpg']] #'highway-mpg' is a column in the dataframe
Y = df['price'] #'price' is a column in the dataframe

lm.fit(X,Y)
```

Here while defining `X` they have used double square brackets `[[]]` and in the case of `Y` used `[]`. I know that square brackets are used for listing in Python and nested listing is possible. But it doesn't seem to be a nested list. Can you please differentiate between them?

Comment: `df[['col']]` gives you a dataframe with 1 column, `df['col']` gives you a series (i.e. the column itself)

Comment: `df['price']` will give you a series, whereas `df[['price']]` gives you a dataframe with only the `'price'` as column.

Comment: From a strictly syntactic standpoint, `df[['highway-mpg']]` is equivalent to `df.__getitem__(['highway-mpg'])`. The outer and inner brackets are treated separately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One does slice the dataframe and return a sub-dataframe, the other select exactly one column and gives it as a `Series`:

- If you pass a list of string to the brackets `[['a', 'c']]`, you'll obtain `DataFrame` which contains only the column you asked
- If you pass a string to the brackets `['a']`, you'll obtain **only** a `Series` which correponds to the name you give

---

Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 4},
    {'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 6},
])

print(df['a'])
# That is a Series
0    1
1    3
Name: a, dtype: int64
# -------------------------------------------
print(df[['a']])
# That is a DataFrame
   a
0  1
1  3
# -------------------------------------------
print(df[['a', 'c']])
# That is a DataFrame
   a  c
0  1  4
1  3  6
```

Answer (score 2):

when you want to use or return a single column of the *data frame* i.e. returns a *Series* then use `df['xyz']` in case you want to return or use multiple columns you can use `df[['xyz','abc','ijk']]` which returns another *data frame* with specified columns.

**Note**

> `df[['xyz']]` this is allowed, but `df['xyz','abc','ijk']` this is not allowed.

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({"Col":[1,2,3],"Row":[2,3,4],"value":[6,5,7],"ree":[0,0,0]})
df1


  Col Row  value ree
0   1   2   6   0
1   2   3   5   0
2   3   4   7   0

df1['Col']
0    1
1    2     # Series object
2    3
Name: Col, dtype: int64

df1[['Col']]
    Col
0   1
1   2      # DataFrame object
2   3

df1[["Col","Row","value"]]
    Col Row value
0   1   2   6
1   2   3   5         # DataFrame object
2   3   4   7
```

in your case `X['h___...']` can also be used as there is only one column

Answer (score 1):

`[[]]` is generally used to pass multiple columns to retrieve from a dataframe. Another key distinction is it returns a `DataFrame`

`[]` is generally used to pass a single column to retrieve from a dataframe. Another key distinction is it returns a `Series`

This is one of the key differences when indexing a dataframe. Both perform the same intended operation with different return types

Comment: I am not sure about your first point as I have seen codes where multiple columns were passed within `[]`.

Comment: You can try that for yourself , you will face errors in doing that :)

Comment: Oh, it was my mistake. I mixed up things. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Machine Learning and Data Analysis, usually *X* denotes independent variables and *y* denotes dependent variable. The goal is to predict single dependent variable *y* using two or many independent variables *X*. And, In Pandas `[[]]` is used to get variable number of columns. That is why `[[]]` used for *X* and `[]` for *y*

Answer (score 0):

[[colname1,colname2,colnamen]] so you are selecting multiple columns from the dataframe whereas ["target_name"] you only need to specify the name of the column since it's just one.